# finder.apply_ngram_filter in nltk.collocations to classify some ngrams

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

How to use finder.apply_ngram_filter in nltk.collocations to rank only certain ngrams and not the contrary to remove certain ngrams. 
Is it this: 
finder.apply_ngram_filter(lambda *w: w not in myngrams)
or there is another way to do that?

Can someone help?

Comment: i'll come back to you after a short toilet break, stay tuned.

Comment: back from toilet and hope the answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common use of `BigramCollocationFinder` is to find top ranking ngrams. E.g.

```
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder, BigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.corpus import genesis

# Initialize an association measure for bigrams.
bigram_measures = BigramAssocMeasures()

# Puts the corpus into a BigramCollocationFinder class.
# Now you can search for bigrams in the corpus
finder2 = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(genesis.words('english-web.txt'))
finder3 = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(genesis.words('english-web.txt'))

# Let's rank the bigrams by their PMI score and output the top 10.
print finder2.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 10)
print
print finder3.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

[out]:

```
[(u'Allon', u'Bacuth'), (u'Ashteroth', u'Karnaim'), (u'Ben', u'Ammi'), (u'En', u'Mishpat'), (u'Jegar', u'Sahadutha'), (u'Salt', u'Sea'), (u'Whoever', u'sheds'), (u'appoint', u'overseers'), (u'aromatic', u'resin'), (u'cutting', u'instrument')]

[(u'olive', u'leaf', u'plucked'), (u'rider', u'falls', u'backward'), (u'sewed', u'fig', u'leaves'), (u'yield', u'royal', u'dainties'), (u'during', u'mating', u'season'), (u'Salt', u'Sea', u').'), (u'Sea', u').', u'Twelve'), (u'Their', u'hearts', u'failed'), (u'Valley', u').', u'Melchizedek'), (u'doing', u'forced', u'labor')]
```

Now we see how the `finder` works, we want more complex functions to clean out results. Let' try to get rid of these nasty trigrams like `(u'Sea', u').', u'Twelve')` and `(u'Valley', u').', u'Melchizedek')`.

Seems like a `).` in the middle of a trigram usually doesn't give a linguistically interesting ngram, so let's try to get rid of them when we rank them:

```
import string
finder3.apply_ngram_filter(lambda w1, w2, w3: w2 == u').' )
print finder3.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

[out]:

```
[(u'olive', u'leaf', u'plucked'), (u'rider', u'falls', u'backward'), (u'sewed', u'fig', u'leaves'), (u'yield', u'royal', u'dainties'), (u'during', u'mating', u'season'), (u'Salt', u'Sea', u').'), (u'Their', u'hearts', u'failed'), (u'doing', u'forced', u'labor'), (u'El', u'Beth', u'El'), (u'own', u'droves', u'apart')]
```

Seems like we clean out the trgram we didn't want but that nasty `u').'` goes into third position, let's get it of it once and for all:

```
finder3.apply_ngram_filter(lambda w1, w2, w3: u').' in [w1,w2,w3])
```

[out]:

```
[(u'olive', u'leaf', u'plucked'), (u'rider', u'falls', u'backward'), (u'sewed', u'fig', u'leaves'), (u'yield', u'royal', u'dainties'), (u'during', u'mating', u'season'), (u'Their', u'hearts', u'failed'), (u'doing', u'forced', u'labor'), (u'El', u'Beth', u'El'), (u'own', u'droves', u'apart'), (u'sandal', u'strap', u'nor')]
```

Yeah now the nasty ngrams are gone. Seems like we just need to give a condition in the lambda function and it will clean out the ones we don't want when ranking them.

Indeed it is, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/collocations.py#L83

```
  def apply_ngram_filter(self, fn):
        """Removes candidate ngrams (w1, w2, ...) where fn(w1, w2, ...)
        evaluates to True.
        """
        self._apply_filter(lambda ng, f: fn(*ng))
```

and this, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/developa/nltk/collocations.py#L68:

```
def _apply_filter(self, fn=lambda ngram, freq: False):
    """Generic filter removes ngrams from the frequency distribution
    if the function returns True when passed an ngram tuple.
    """
    tmp_ngram = FreqDist()
    for ngram, freq in iteritems(self.ngram_fd):
        if not fn(ngram, freq):
            tmp_ngram[ngram] = freq
    self.ngram_fd = tmp_ngram
```

The lambda looks a little complex but actually it's just a condition that's doing something like this (it's not exactly doing the following but you can understand it as such):

```
def aaply_filter(trigrams, condition):
    return [ng for ng in trigrams if not if condition]
```

So let's go back to your question, let's say our blacklist ngrams are:

```
blacklist = ["olive leaf plucked", "during mating searson"]
```

First you got to tuplize them (if they're not):

```
>>> blacklist = ["olive leaf plucked", "during mating searson"]
>>> blacklist = [tuple(b.split()) for b in blacklist]
>>> blacklist
[('olive', 'leaf', 'plucked'), ('during', 'mating', 'searson')]
```

With this:

```
blacklist = ["olive leaf plucked", "during mating searson"]
blacklist = [tuple(b.split()) for b in blacklist]
finder3.apply_ngram_filter(lambda w1, w2, w3: (w1,w2,w3) in blacklist)

print finder3.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

[out]:

```
[(u'rider', u'falls', u'backward'), (u'sewed', u'fig', u'leaves'), (u'yield', u'royal', u'dainties'), (u'during', u'mating', u'season'), (u'Salt', u'Sea', u').'), (u'Sea', u').', u'Twelve'), (u'Their', u'hearts', u'failed'), (u'Valley', u').', u'Melchizedek'), (u'doing', u'forced', u'labor'), (u'El', u'Beth', u'El')]
```

**Voila !!!**

Alternatively, you can also use this function, if you don't want to tuplize your ngrams, the following yield the same output:

```
blacklist = ["olive leaf plucked", "during mating searson"]
finder3.apply_ngram_filter(lambda w1, w2, w3: " ".join([w1,w2,w3]) in blacklist)

print finder3.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

So here's the full script:

```
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramCollocationFinder, TrigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.corpus import genesis


# Initialize an association measure for bigrams.
bigram_measures = BigramAssocMeasures()
trigram_measures = TrigramAssocMeasures()

# Puts the corpus into a BigramCollocationFinder class.
# Now you can search for bigrams in the corpus
finder2 = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(genesis.words('english-web.txt'))
finder3 = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(genesis.words('english-web.txt'))


blacklist = ["olive leaf plucked", "during mating searson"]
finder3.apply_ngram_filter(lambda w1, w2, w3: " ".join([w1,w2,w3]) in blacklist)

print finder3.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

If you want to do the reverse, it's normally call a whitelist, simply do:

```
whitelist = ["olive leaf plucked", "during mating searson"]
finder3.apply_ngram_filter(lambda w1, w2, w3: " ".join([w1,w2,w3]) not in whitelist)
```

Comment: alvas  But I want to do the contrary, so I do not want to remove the blacklist, but I will rank only the blacklist removing all the ngrams in the text.

Comment: so filter out by adding a `not` to the condition =)